# Create appointment in selected calendar (VSTO vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-calendar

I am developing a VSTO outlook addin, that will create an appointment/meeting. I use the following code to create the appointment/meeting:

Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)

If the user clicks into a different calendar ( second account or an account that they have delegate access) to how can I create the appointment in the selected calendar?

I know I can do this with the below code but how do I get the correct folder ?

```
items = calendarFolder.Items;
appItem = items.Add(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem) as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
appItem.Save();
appItem.Display(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the currently selected folder to create an appointment in, use `Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder`. If you want the Calendar folder in a store other than the default one, use `Store.GetDEfaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)` (where `Store` comes from the `Application.Session.Stores` collection). If you want Calendar folder from another Exchange mailbox, call `Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder` (`Recipient` object needed by `GetSharedDefaultFolder` can come from `Application.Session.CreateRecipient`).